# Finding category values that ara minimum for some variable - R

Tags: r, dataframe

Let I have the below data frame(df):

```
x=c("a1","a2","a3","b1","b2","b3")
y1=c(4,2,1,1,5,8)
y2=c(7,1,9,3,2,10)

df<-data.frame(x,y1,y2)
```

Namely:

```
> df
   x y1 y2
1 a1  4  7
2 a2  2  1
3 a3  1  9
4 b1  1  3
5 b2  5  2
6 b3  8 10
```

I want to find the value of x which is mininmum of for both y1 and y2 by group of x.

I want to reach the below output for df:

```
y1   y2
a3   a2
b1   b2
```

How can I reach that recult? My original data is much bigger.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a clear group column defined we can create one first. For the example shown we can remove all the numbers from `x` column and use that as a group column. For each group we can then find out minimum value in the column and get corresponding `x` value of it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(group = sub('\\d+', '', x)) %>%
  summarise(across(y1:y2, ~x[which.min(.)]))

#  group y1    y2   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a3    a2   
#2 b     b1    b2
```

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(grp = str_remove(x, "\\d+")) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ x[which.min(.)]))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
#  grp   y1    y2   
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 a     a3    a2   
#2 b     b1    b2
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option

```
> setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(v) x[which.min(v)]), .(grp = gsub("\\d", "", x))]
   grp y1 y2
1:   a a3 a2
2:   b b1 b2
```